# Spring MVC and Request Attributes

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, controller

I think the original question was confusing.

I have a HashMap that needs to be a Collection from a database that I'd like to send to a view via a Spring Controller. I don't want to put this HashMap in the model.addAttribute() because the Spring Model object returns a Map and my JSP needs the collection to be a `Collection<Object>`. If I set my HashMap.values() in a request.setAttribute, how do I go about dispatching that request variable to the view if my method is returning a String?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    model.addAttribute("surveys", mySurveys); //this is a map and I need a Collection<Object>

    //So I'd like to do this, but how do I get to the "evaluations" object in a view if I'm not dispatching it (like below)??
    request.setAttribute("evaluations", mySurveys);

    //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("pathToResource");
    //rd.forward(request, response);

    return "home";
}
```

EDIT: The Spring Tag library cannot be used for this particular usecase.

Thanks.

Comment: You use Spring MVC and can't use Spring Taglibs, which is **in** Spring MVC jar - why not?

Comment: I can use it, but the TagLib I'm using fits the Interface of the system we're working with. Users expect it to look a certain way.

Comment: so if you add it to the model using addAttribute can you not access it simply with ${surveys} within home.jsp?

Comment: I get an exception because the tag (that builds a datatable) expects a Collection object and not a map.

Comment: can you show that code that declares and instantiates mSurveys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If mySurveys is a Map, then perhaps you can put mySurveys.values() into the ModelMap instead of mySurveys (Also, are you intending to use a **ModelMap** instead of a Model?)

In the code below, surveys would be a Collection of Objects and would be accessible in the jsp via ${surveys}

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map<String,Object> mySurveys = getMySurveys();
    modelMap.addAttribute("surveys", mySurveys.values());
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I realized this about an hour before you posted and yes I need Model and not ModelMap. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused as to what `ModelMap` is.

You can annotate whatever variable you want to access in the view by `@ModelAttribute` and Spring will automatically instantiate it, and add it to the `ModelMap`. In the view, you can use it like:

```
<form:form modelattribute="myAttribute">
    <form:input path="fieldInAttribute">
</form:form>
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: I'm not going to be able to use the Spring Tags, but I'm working with another framework that has it's own api and taglib. I'll have to display it using the ${variable} syntax.

Comment: I posted what I was trying to do